# How to correctly plot the step response of a MIMO system with python control package

Tags: python, controls, response, ode

I would need to plot the step responses of a MIMO system with the python control package.

I've tried so far by using the function `step_response`, that however converts the system into a *SISO* before computing the step response, so that only one set of output is computed.

I then tried using the function `forced_response` with different setup for the input (i.e. constant unity value, `numpy` array of ones etc..., just for the sake of trying).
I get different step responses, so related to other output, but not all the responses (i.e. number of input x number of output).

Here is a minimum sample code that implements a simple 2nd order model with 2 input and 4 output and dummy data. In attachment a plot of the responses I get.

[stepResponses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9I3J.png)

In my test I first run the `step_response` function, `yout` results to be of size `4 x size_time` (so only the first 4 output are excited).

Then I run the `forced_response` function, and `youtForced` still results of size `4 x size_time`, instead of size `4 x size_time x 2` (or similar) as I expected (in the hypothesis `forced_response` treats the system as a MIMO).

Is there a way to have full control of the step response via the `forced_response` function (similarly to what the MATLAB step function does)?

Unfortunately there is poor documentation and very few practical examples about this.

Many thanks to who can help.

```
from control import ss, step_response, forced_response
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sz = 2

f1 = 1*2*np.pi
f2 = 1.5*2*np.pi
OM2 = [-f1**2, -f2**2]
ZI = [-2*f1*0.01, -2*f2*0.01]

A11 = np.zeros((sz, sz))
A12 = np.eye(sz)
A21 = np.diag(OM2)
A22 = np.diag(ZI)

A = np.vstack((np.concatenate((A11, A12), axis=1), np.concatenate((A21, A22), axis=1)))

B1 = np.zeros((sz, sz))    
B2 = [[1e-6, 1e-7],[2e-6, 2e-7]]
B = np.vstack((B1, B2))

C1 = np.zeros((sz, sz*2))
C1[0] = [1e-4, 2*1e-4, 3*1e-4, 5*1e-5]
C1[1] = [2e-4, 3.5*1e-4, 1.5*1e-4, 2*1e-5]
C2 = np.zeros((sz*2, sz))
C = np.concatenate((C1.T, C2), axis=1)

D = np.zeros((sz*2, sz))

sys = ss(A, B, C, D)

tEnd = 1
time = np.arange(0, tEnd, 1e-3)
tout, youtStep = step_response(sys, T=time)
tout, youtForced, xout = forced_response(sys, T=time, U=1.0)
plt.figure()
for k, y in enumerate(youtStep):
    plt.subplot(4,1,k+1)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(tout, y,label='step')
    plt.plot(tout, youtForced[k], '--r',label='forced')
    if k == 0:
        plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the step response is easily manageable via the function `control.matlab.step` which actually allows the selection of the different input of the MIMO system, something I initially ignored, but was well reported in the official documentation:

https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.1/generated/control.matlab.step.html

Here's the output [[MIMO step response output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lqTN.png)]

Luckily it was an easy fix :)

```
from control import ss
import control.matlab as ctl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sz = 2

f1 = 1*2*np.pi
f2 = 1.5*2*np.pi
OM2 = [-f1**2, -f2**2]
ZI = [-2*f1*0.01, -2*f2*0.01]

A11 = np.zeros((sz, sz))
A12 = np.eye(sz)
A21 = np.diag(OM2)
A22 = np.diag(ZI)

A = np.vstack((np.concatenate((A11, A12), axis=1), np.concatenate((A21, A22), axis=1)))

B1 = np.zeros((sz, sz))    
B2 = [[1e-6, 1e-7],[2e-6, 2e-7]]
B = np.vstack((B1, B2))

C1 = np.zeros((sz, sz*2))
C1[0] = [1e-4, 2*1e-4, 3*1e-4, 5*1e-5]
C1[1] = [2e-4, 3.5*1e-4, 1.5*1e-4, 2*1e-5]
C2 = np.zeros((sz*2, sz))
C = np.concatenate((C1.T, C2), axis=1)

D = np.zeros((sz*2, sz))

sys = ss(A, B, C, D)

tEnd = 100
time = np.arange(0, tEnd, 1e-3)
yy1, tt1 = ctl.step(sys, T=time, input=0)
yy2, tt2 = ctl.step(sys, T=time, input=1)
plt.figure()
for k in range(0, len(yy1[1,:])):
    plt.subplot(4,1,k+1)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(tt1, yy1[:,k], label='input=0')
    plt.plot(tt2, yy2[:,k], label='input=1')
    if k == 0:
        plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
```